# EXCEPT SELECT SQL Query in DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2, except

I'm new to DB2 and couldn't find anything relating to `EXCEPT` queries [except] quite simple examples. I'm trying to compare values across two tables in order to return values which appear in `TABLE_A` but not in `TABLE_B`. The problem is that the columns being compared do not key exactly, but require some manipulation first.

`ID_1` field from `TABLE_A` looks like this: `000   999`

`ID_2` field from `TABLE_B` looks like this: `111-000999`

So by massaging the data from each ID we get the key value of `000999` for this sample row. This should result in this row being excluded from the query result as the data is present in both tables.

```
SELECT REPLACE (ID_1, ' ','') AS ID_1_TRIM
FROM MYDB.TABLE_A
EXCEPT 
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID_2,5,10) 
FROM MYDB.TABLE_B
```

This syntax doesn't work, it appears to return all the values in `TABLE_A`, even though the massaged key values also appear in `TABLE_B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try to trim may be

```
 SELECT trim(REPLACE (ID_1, ' ','')) AS ID_1_TRIM
 FROM MYDB.TABLE_A
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT trim(SUBSTRING(ID_2,5,10)) FROM MYDB.TABLE_B
```

or cast

```
 SELECT cast(trim(REPLACE (ID_1, ' ','')) as varchar(15)) AS ID_1_TRIM
 FROM MYDB.TABLE_A
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT cast(trim(SUBSTRING(ID_2,5,10)) as varchar(15))  FROM MYDB.TABLE_B
```

In my iseries your query work, are you sur it's space characteres in ID_1 ?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried these alternatives and the result coming back is still all the values in `TABLE_A`. When I run each `SELECT` query separately, the values returned are in the same format and should match.

Comment: really Strange. and if you do it : SELECT * FROM MYDB.TABLE_A f1 exception join MYDB.TABLE_B f2
on cast(trim(REPLACE (f1.ID_1, ' ','')) as varchar(15)) = cast(trim(SUBSTRING(f2.ID_2,5,10)) as varchar(15))

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with the data, however the trim technique was useful as there were hidden spaces, thanks